# Proof that field trace in $GF(2^k)$ maps half of the elements to 0 and the other half to 1.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, finite-fields

I'm reading a proof on the solutions of equation $a = z^z + z$ in $GF(2^k)$, that is, the finite field with $2^k$. At some point it uses that the trace function defined as $Tr(a) = a + a^2 +  \cdots + a^{2^{k-1}}$ maps half of the elements of $GF(2^k)$ to 0 and half of the elements to 1. I'm trying to proof it.

**My approach**

The solutions of the equations are proved to be of the form $\theta$ and $\theta + 1$. As the trace is linear we have $Tr(\theta + 1) = Tr(\theta) + Tr(1)$.

If k is odd then $Tr(1) = 1 + 1^2 + \cdots + 1^{2^{k-1}} = 1$ so it is natural to define from the set $$A = \{ a \in GF(2^k):Tr(a) = 0\}$$ to $$B = \{ a \in GF(2^k):Tr(a) = 1\}$$ the mapping $f(a) = a+1$.

This mapping appears to me to a bijection.

What happens if k is even?

Comment: If $Tr(a)=0$ for every $a$ then you have a polynomial of degree $2^{k-1}$ with $2^k$ roots.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The trace is a linear form, so it is a map

> $$Tr: GF(2^k)\to GF(2).$$

But then linear algebra tells us (rank-nullity) that the null space of this surjective (see below) map is isomorphic to $GF(2^{k-1})$, because it is a vector subspace of $GF(2^k)$ of dimension $k-1$. By definition the null space is things that map to $0$, and the cardinality is clearly half of all the elements, so the rest must go to $1$.

- This is surjective because $Tr$ is the sum of the Galois conjugates, and you know the Galois group is cyclic and generated by $x\mapsto x^2$, so anything of trace $0$ satisfies $x+x^2+x^4+x^8+\ldots +x^{2^{k-1}}=0$. But only $2^{k-1}$ things can possibly satisfy this, so **something** has trace $1$.

Comment: Can the downvoter explain what they think is wrong??

Comment: I was not the downvoter, but you didn't explain why $Tr\neq 0$ (see my comment above). Also it might be simpler to speak about (additive) groups rather than invoking linear algebra, but everybody can choose.

Comment: @user8268 I agree on the non-triviality of trace bit, I'll include that. As for group kernels vs linear algebra, I'm about evenly split since linear algebra is Occam's razor in this case but likely they are more recently acquainted with additive groups. Since the latter involves showing the kernel has size **exactly** $2^{k-1}$ without linear algebra though, I think the current version is probably simplest overall (by my aesthetic). Thanks for all the feedback!